# Update control in another UserControl C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, controls

I currently am using an click event to save file data (via Background worker) inside a UserControl which at each step updates a control in the main window which is working well and gets the update from the UserControl. Code below.

*UPDATE: I should state that i'm using FirstFloor MUI Framework and the mui:ModernTab in the Mainwindow.*

**MainWindow.xaml Control (control is hidden until update happens)(using x:FieldModifier="public")**

```
<StatusBar x:Name="mainStatus" Height="24" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Panel.ZIndex="999999" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" BorderBrush="#FFBDBDBD" Background="Transparent" Margin="0,0,0,-15">
        <StackPanel x:Name="global_message" Height="28" Width="718" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="0,4,0,0" Visibility="Hidden">
            <fa:ImageAwesome x:Name="global_message_block_icon" x:FieldModifier="public" Height="12" Width="15" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Visibility="Hidden" >
                <fa:ImageAwesome.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"/>
                </fa:ImageAwesome.Foreground>
            </fa:ImageAwesome>
            <TextBlock x:Name="global_message_block" x:FieldModifier="public" Margin="19,-13,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="15" Width="850" FontSize="12" FontWeight="Bold" Visibility="Hidden" >
                <TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource AccentColor}"/>
                </TextBlock.Foreground>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </StatusBar>
```

**UserControl (MyControlA.xaml.cs) code to update the selected control in MainWindow + possibly update another control in another UserControl(ProcessTools/PODDuplicate.xaml)**

```
//Works well
foreach (System.Windows.Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
  {
     if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
        {
          (window as MainWindow).global_message.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
          (window as MainWindow).global_message_block.Text = "";
          (window as MainWindow).global_message_block.ToolTip = "";

         }
 }

 //Code to access ProcessTools.PODDuplicate(ProcessTools/PODDuplicate.xaml) which has the control I wish to change/update
 foreach (UserControl usercontrol in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
         {
             if (usercontrol.GetType() == typeof(UserControl))
             {
                 (usercontrol as ProcessTools.PODDuplicate).form_process_pod.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;

             }

   }
```

Problem is that;

```
foreach (UserControl usercontrol in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
```

is never going to work as the object that needs updating is a control and not a Window Type.

Is there away to access the "other UserControl" and update a control setting?

Comment: If you can access `MainWindow` and `MainWindow` contains the `UserControl` you need to update, then you can access `UserControl` too through `MainWindow` instance

Comment: I should state that i'm using FirstFloor MUI Framework and the mui:ModernTab in the Mainwindow...Added to question info